# How to perform a Elastsearch multi_match AND a BOOL together?

Tags: elasticsearch

i have try to use the query as below ,

```
 {
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "range":{
                  "@timestamp":{
                     "from":"2018-09-01T08:35:11.000Z",
                     "to":"2018-10-01T08:35:11.000Z"
                  }
               }
            },
            "multi_match":{
               "query":"世界の人々の祝祭、第23回冬季",
               "fields":"message"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":10000
}
```

but get the error message :

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
  {
        "type" : "json_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@4eacc26c; line: 21, column: 27]"
      }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

but if without timestamp range ,it's works

```
"query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "世界の人々の祝祭、第23回冬季",
      "fields": [
        "message"
      ]
     }
 }
```

What is wrong in the request ? How to perform a multi_match AND a BOOL together ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `multi_match` query inside curly braces as well

```
 {
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "range":{
                  "@timestamp":{
                     "from":"2018-09-01T08:35:11.000Z",
                     "to":"2018-10-01T08:35:11.000Z"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
              "multi_match":{
                 "query":"世界の人々の祝祭、第23回冬季",
                 "fields":"message"
              }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":10000
}
```

Comment: ,I want to get the message field that contain the substring "世界の人々の祝祭、第23回冬季" , but from your query will get other document that didn't match the message field rule

Comment: Not sure I understand, both constraints are in a must clause

Comment: ,but results have message field didn't contain the substring "世界の人々の祝祭、第23回冬季"

Comment: Well, I was merely fixing the `json_parse_exception` you were getting. You didn't really mention what the query was supposed to return.

Comment: ,sorry I am not to mention that I want ,do you know how to get the return ?

Comment: I think this question is solved and you should create another one with your specific issue (so we don't mmix two problems into one question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181125/discussion-between-georgetovrea-and-val).